# In WordPress. How to insert <meta> tag in the <head> area of a specific page with coding (without any plugin)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hook

I want to add a meta tag for my site description inside the head area of a **specific page** before the body tag opens on the WordPress website.

Comment: Maybe useful? [How to Add Meta Tags, Keywords & Descriptions in WordPress](https://www.theme-junkie.com/how-to-add-meta-tags-in-wordpress/). Scroll down to 'edit `theme file'. I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hook for wp_head() in your functions.php theme file ( or plugin ).

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    
    if ( is_page( 11 ) ) {
        echo '<meta tag... for page_id = 11>';
    }

    if ( is_post( 22 ) ) {
        echo '<meta tag... for post_id = 22>';
    }

});
```

Answer (score -2):

go to Dashboard > pages > open page with editor
go to HTML  find the HTML and add your tags
if  this not works for you edit your Cms  and add custom Scripts and make change

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).